# Compile error with templated adapter as rhs of operator overload instance

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

I've been trying to use a templated adapter to enable use with an overloaded operator.  I'm getting a compile error (gcc 4.5.2) that seems a contradiction to me.  I'd like to know why and how to get around it.  Below is simplified code that illustrates the problem.

```
// The adapter
template <typename T>
class A {
    T t;
public:
    A(T t_) : t(t_) {}
};

// Utility function to return an adaptor
template <typename T>
A<T> make_A(T t) {
    A<T> a(t);
    return a;
}

// The operator overload on the adapter
template <typename T>
A<T> &operator<<(A<T> &a, int) {
    return a;
}

// Shows use case
int main(int,char**) {
    auto aa = make_A(1);
    aa << 2;        // Compiles

    // Desired use:
    make_A(4) << 5; // Compile Error
}
```

The error messages:

```
main_operatorinsert.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main_operatorinsert.cpp:28:22: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘make_A [with T = int](4) << 5’
main_operatorinsert.cpp:18:11: note: candidate is: A<T>& operator<<(A<T>&, int) [with T = int]
```

Why does the line "aa << 2;" compile, where the line "make_A(4) << 5;" does not?  make_A returns the same type as aa.  Why is the compiler getting a mismatch?  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_A` returns an *rvalue*, but your `operator<<` requires a non-const *lvalue* as the first argument. You need to redesign a bit around this, if you really need to support `make_A(4) << 5;` you could make `operator<<` a member function, but beware that returning an *lvalue* reference from it is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a temporary (`make_A(4)`) to a non-const lvalue reference.

You could try making it a `const` reference, or just avoid the temporary. In C++11 you can use rvalue references.

See: [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)